# Are functions with odd-numbered exponents parabolas?

Tags: functions

Or are only functions with even-numbered exponents called 'parabolas' and, if so, is there another name for functions with odd-numbered exponents like cubics and quintics?

Comment: Neither, a parabola is given by a polynomial of the form $a x^2 + b x + c$ with $a \neq 0$. There is not really any other customary name for polynomials of odd degree other than "polynomials of odd degree"

Comment: That depends on how you define parabola. It's just a word. Curves defined by $y=f(x),$ with $f(x)$ being a polynomial of at least degree two are often called parabolas of order $\text{deg}f(x).$

Answer (score 1):

Only functions where the highest degree term has degree $2$ give rise to graphs called parabolas. The graph of $x\mapsto x^4$ is *not* a parabola.

I don't think there is a name for higher degree curves, other than "cubic curve", "quartic curve", "quintic curve", and so on. They just don't have the same tradition behind them, and as such they haven't received fancy names.

Comment: Do you mean $x^4$ is not a parabola simply by convention or for some technical reason? I've assumed for a while that $x^4$ is a special case of $x^2$, since $x^4=(x^2)^2$, suggesting that we might think of $x^4$ as a 'duplicate quadratic'.

Comment: @mjc: by that logic, _every_ non-negative function would be a parabola, which is absurd. For instance, you could say that $|x|=(\sqrt x)^2$ is a "special case" of $x^2$.

Comment: I wouldn't call that absurd, but I agree it's undesirable.

Comment: @mjc A parabola has a concrete, geometric definition and several equivalent geometric properties (which property is the definition, and which properties are derived is a matter of convention and preference), the same way a circle does. The quadratic functions are the only ones whose graphs fulfill the requirements of said definition.

Answer (score 1):

A parabola is a particular kind of curve. The standard examples are the graphs of the quadratic equations $y=ax^2 + bx + c$ in the usual coordinate system. The Greeks knew them as sections of a cone.

The graph of $y=x^4$ has a roughly similar shape, but it's not a parabola.

Answer (score 1):

Only second degree polynomials $$y=ax^2+bx+c$$ where $a\ne 0$ are parabolas.

For third degree polynomials sometimes $S$ shaped is used but cubic is more common.
For higher degrees quartic, quintic and so forth are used.
 I call them "polymomials of n-th degree" which serves the purpose  without using fancy names.

Answer (score 1):

A [function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Function.html) is a *weaker* definition of a parabola (as in there are parabolas that are not functions since parabolas can map the same input to two different points on the plane. A [parabola](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Parabola.html) has a strict definition that isn't quite as intuitive (see Wolfram link).

However, to answer your question more directly, no. Parabolas come in all different shapes and forms, but the precise definition follows from "conic forms". This is a fancy definition for just a curve you'd get if you took any subsection of a cone. Even with the strict mathematical definition of conic forms, no odd functions fall under the parabolas.

Most parabolas fall under the form of $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$, however there are rotations to this that also count as parabolas (such as the function $(y+3)^2=12(x-1)$). You can think of parabolas as curves that satisfies $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ where $a$ is non-zero, along with any linear transformations of it (translation, rotation and reflection).

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong. Not every curve with the symmetry you describe is a parabola. The link to Wolfram is correct.

Comment: You're right, edited.

Comment: That's better, but still not quite right. You correctly note that a parabola is just a particular shape. Saying a function is a weaker definition is just confusing. What you mean is that if you put a parabola on the usual coordinate plane sometimes (in fact most of the time) it will not be the graph of a function. But a parabola is never a function.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of a function may change direction one less times than its power. For example a parabola may go down, then up, or vice versa. A cubic may go up-down-up or up-sideways-up or some other plot with two changes of directional $curve$. A quartic will change direction three times and so on. As Ethan Bolker noted, they can have a similar shape but not quite. We can see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=graph+x%5E4%2B11x%5E3%2Bx%5E2%2Bx%2B1) how there are $3$ curve changes in a quartic but, stepping farther back, the whole think looks similar to a parabola.

Still, only a quadratic produces a parabola.